# Ruby Float#round method behaves incorrectly with round(2)

Tags: ruby, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ruby-1.9.3

I learned that it's recommended to use `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`, but this one is either a bug or highlights the esoteric nature of `Float`. It seems that `Float#round(2)` has a problem with "1.015", "1.025" and "1.035".

```
1.015.round(2)
 => 1.01    # => WRONG .. should be 1.02
1.025.round(2)
 => 1.02    # => WRONG .. should be 1.03
1.035.round(2)
 => 1.03    # => WRONG .. should be 1.04
1.045.round(2)
 => 1.05    # => CORRECT
1.016.round(2)
 => 1.02    # => CORRECT
```

`round(3)` works fine.

```
1.0015.round(3)
 => 1.002  # => CORRECT
1.235.round(2)
 => 1.24   # => CORRECT
```

To monkey patch this in a Rails app, I did this:

```
config/initializers/float_mp.rb

require 'bigdecimal'

class Float
  def round(val=0)
     BigDecimal.new(self.to_s).round(val).to_f
  end
end
```

This seems to be a weird and expensive work-around. Could this be a bug in `Float#round`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the way binary floating-point works. If you want such strict behavior, your "expensive word-around" is the way to do.

Comment: You're looking for predictable *binary* approximations to results of *decimal* rounding of *binary* approximations to *decimal* halfway cases.  That way lies madness!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAICS the ruby round() works correctly. Presumably it's just a wrapper around the round() function in libm anyway.

So the reason is that your floating point literals cannot be represented exactly in binary. E.g. "1.015" printed with a few more decimals gives "1.0149999999999999"; thus when rounding to two decimal digits, 1.01 is closer to the true value than 1.02. And so on for your other examples as well.

Also keep in mind that the default IEEE 754 rounding mode is "Round to nearest, ties to even" which is not the same as "Round to nearest, ties away from zero" which is what you may be familiar with from school.